# How to install muxviz with R?

Tags: r, muxviz

I installed any SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS for install `muxviz` (octave,R,GDAL). But when I write `source('muxVizGUI.R')` in R environment, this error is showed for me:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'muxVizGUI.R': No such file or directory
```

I unzip `muxzip` in desktop. How can I install muxviz with R? Is there any way to install muxviz in windows 8?

Comment: What is the output of `getwd()`?

Comment: You will have to either move your working directory to desktop (`setwd(c:/users/parisa/Desktop)`) or specify the full path to `muxVizGUI.R`, e.g. `source("c:/users/parisa/Desktop/muxVizGUI.R")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your directory to the "muxViz-master" folder on your desktop:

```
setwd("C:/Users/.../muxViz-master")
```